# Structure memory allocation to its member

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have seen the allocating memory to the structure like this

```
   ///enter code here
   for(i = 0; i<10; i++)
     s->a[i].mem = malloc(sizeof(*a[0]));
```

What does it mean???it is allocating memory for a or for mem. I am confused.

if it is allocating to pointer mem?? I have seen in the code,they accessing by

```
mem[0] = bla...bla...
mem[1] = bla...bla...
```

whether it's legal???

Comment: You're missing a `)` to close the call to `malloc`.

Comment: You assign to the `mem` member, so that's where the pointer to the allocated memory is stored.

Comment: s->a[i].mem = malloc(sizeof(*a[0]); Syntax Missing here

Answer (score 3):

`a[]` should be a array of struct, where each `a[i]` means a struct.

In The struct `mem` should be a pointer of struct type (self pointing). So the expression.

```
s->a[i].mem = malloc(sizeof(*a[0]));
```

Allocates memory dynamically using malloc and assigns address to `mem`

Something like:

```
struct  xyx{
   int data;
   struct  xyx   *mem;
};

 struct  xyx a[10];
```

So: `a[0]` type of `struct xyx`.

and expression:

```
a[i].mem = malloc( sizeof(*a[0]));
```

same as:

```
a[i].mem = malloc( sizeof(struct xyz);
```

**Second:** 
Now, What is  `s->a[i]` ?

`s` is again a pointer variable of some other struct type, in which there is an array `a[]` of type struct `xyz`.  Something like:

```
struct abc{ 
  struct  xyx a[10];
};
```

and `s` should be:

```
struct abc  x;
struct abc  *s = &x;
```

or memory to `s` should be allocated dynamically. So `s -> a[i]` to access member.

So expression:

```
s -> a[i].mem =  malloc(sizeof(*a[0]));
^    ^     ^ 
|    |     is pointer to struct of type that same as type of a[0]   
|    array of struct's elements,    
s is pointer to a struct in which `a[]` is datamember
```

Answer (score 1):

This will allocate memory of size `*a[0]` and pointer to the start of this memory block will be saved in `mem` pointer.

Answer (score 0):

The code allocates a block that has the same size as the object that `a[0]` points to. It then stores a pointer to that block in `s->a[i].mem`.

Answer (score 0):

It means allocate a block of memory the same size as the thing that a[0] points to

This memory allocation is pointed to by s->a[i].mem

So, I'd guess that elsewhere in the program a[0] is set up and then this fragment uses the contents of a[0] to find the size for the other members of a[]